# Email Annotations for Promotion tab: Deal badge shows. Promo image does not. Logo only from Primary but not in Promo tab

Tags: gmail-promo-tab

** Email annotations for the Promotion tab **
We've only bee getting a partial experience in the Promo tab.

- The deal badge shows fine, consistently.
- The logo only shows when highlighting promos from the Primary inbox.
- The logo does not show when displaying the promo info in the Promo tab.
- The PromotionCard image showed at one point during early tests. But it does not show now.
- Sent email to our ***promotabtesting@gmail.com email.
- Email app is latest version and using default settings.

Does Gmail care where the images are hosted? Trying to figure out why the images don't render consistently. It appears fine in the Annotation Preview tool.

Below is the code we used (microformats since Salesforce Marketing Cloud strips JS). By the way, we tried the same in JSON on a manually created email, and the experience was the same as described above.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="OurCompany" />
    <meta itemprop="logo" content="https://..........png" />
</div>
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/EmailMessage">
    <meta itemprop="subjectLine" content="Cheers! Product Name..... is Back." />
</div>
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/DiscountOffer">
    <meta itemprop="description" content="20% OFF" />
</div>
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PromotionCard">
    <meta itemprop="image" content="https://..........jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Some basic *context* please! This is about Gmail somehow‽

Comment: @deceze 100% about Gmail. This is about the email annotations for the Promotion tab as explained here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/promotab/overview. I've updated the subject to be more clear.